# Center a H2 inside a div element

Tags: html, css, header, stylesheet

I want to center h2 inside #top but `vertical-align:middle` doesn't work... I have no idea what to do!

```
#top {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: rgba(89,144,222,.6);
}
#top h2{
    text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-family:"Impact";
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

effect is - http://puu.sh/2mz5M

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your CSS and is most likely something wrong with the HTML your using. Evidence of this working can be found http://jsfiddle.net/GbGGQ/ additional this more ideal on Stack Overflow but more than likely a duplicate.

Comment: Your question isn't clear: do you want to centre it horizontally or vertically, or both? You have `text-align: center;` but mention "vert-aliignt middle"... please clarify. Also, sharing the HTML would help – CSS may be correct, HTML might be wrong, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see, you have height defined for div, which is great for this situation. You can do this:

```
#top h2{
    text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-family:"Impact";
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you set the line-height of the div. See Method 2 here:

http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Give a fixed height and line-height to vertically align and text-align: center to center the text.

```
#top {
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    background-color: rgba(89,144,222,.6);
}

    #top h2{
        text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
        font-family:"Impact";
        font-size: 50px;
    }
```

**Jsfiddle :** http://jsfiddle.net/XvFCT/